# how can I test this redux action in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, axios

I want to test this redux action which uses axios, I have succesfully tested the success path but I can't reach the catch block to complete the code coverage. I'm mocking axios using a **mocks** folder in jest.

```
export const fetchTasks = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchLoading());
    axios
        .get(url + '/all', { mode: 'cors' })
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(setTasks(response.data));
            dispatch(fetchDone());
        })
        .catch(response => {
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(fetchDone());
        });
};
```

this is my success path test which implements a redux store and expects loading and setTasks to run and the setTasks action to have a payload that matches my mockObjects tasks list.

```
describe('when fetchTasks is dispatched', () => {
    it('should dispatch other actions with correct payloads', async () => {
        const store = testStore();
        const spyOnDispatch = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
        await tasksActions.fetchTasks()(store.dispatch, store.getState);
        expect(spyOnDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'FETCH_LOADING' });
        expect(spyOnDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'SET_TASKS', tasks: mockObjects.mockTasks });
        expect(spyOnDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'FETCH_DONE' });
        expect(store.getState().tasksState.tasks).toEqual(mockObjects.mockTasks);
    });
});
```

I've tried to use this code to make the catch code to run but it executes the same code as the success path and sets the tasks list to undefined

```
 mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject({ status: 400 }));
```

Comment: You could use something like [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) instead of manually trying to mock Axios.

Answer (score 0):

When testing frontend code that makes HTTP request, I suggest using a mocking library to create fake responses. Two that I am familar with are [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) and [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock). You should be able to throw an error in your mock response code so that it triggers the `catch()` branch.